# How to have Get Travel Time to pass ETA rather than Travel Time

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

When I use the **Get Travel Time** action from an address the magic variable that is passed out of **Get Travel Time** is **Travel Time**.

[image: Example of Get Travel Time passing out Travel Time value]

However, when I look at the **Home ETA** shortcut from the Gallery the **Get Travel Time** action creates an **ETA** magic variable rather than **Travel Time**.

[image: Example of Get Travel Time passing out ETA]

How do I get **Travel Time** to pass **ETE** rather than **Travel Time**?

I understand that if I copy the **Home ETA** Shortcut I can probably just reuse the **ETA** value from that step in my own Shortcut but 1) it is frustrating that I cannot get my shortcut to behave the way the example does and 2) I feel there is something going on here that I don't understand.

Comment: Can't you just calculate it? Current time + Travel time = ETA?